# Img not showing in Safari, does show in Chrome

Tags: html, css, image, google-chrome, safari

I feel like I'm missing something here. I've got a website for a client where the images show up perfect in Chrome and just fail to appear entirely in Safari. I'm using only HTML and CSS. Any ideas?
The live site is at [angelahartley.net](http://angelahartley.net)

HTML:

```
<ul class="gallery">
<li><img src="img/home1.jpg" title="newborn greta: by Josh Muir" alt="newborn greta in arms"></li>
<li><img src="img/home2.jpg" title="newborn greta: by Josh Muir" alt="baby greta on a rainbow"></li>
<li><img src="img/home3.jpg" title="photo by Santa Cruz Birth Photography" alt="baby, mom, and dad in birthing pool"></li>
</ul>
```

CSS:

```
    .gallery {
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
    background-color: #947960;
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -moz-box;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: nowrap;
    justify-content: space-around;
    align-items: center;
}
.gallery li {
    float: left;
    width: 33.33333333%;
    margin: 4px .5% 1px .5%;
    padding: 0 ;

}
img {
    max-width: 100%;
    border: 1px solid #00565E;
    border-radius: 2.5%;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `position:relative;` to your `.gallery li{}` class

You do not need any other updates.

The problem is the z-index gets lost unless you define the position as something other than the default 'static' value for position.

```
.gallery li{
   position:relative;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove all display rules from the css and it should work.

Answer (score 0):

It is your `display:-webkit-box;` that seems to be the issue. Remove it and it should be fine.

```
.gallery {
width: 100%;
margin: 0 auto;
padding: 0;
list-style: none;
background-color: #947960;
display: -moz-box;
display: -ms-flexbox;
display: flex;
flex-wrap: nowrap;
justify-content: space-around;
align-items: center;
}
```